# Jmeter + Maven: how to add a jar file to JMeter /lib/ext folder

Tags: jmeter, maven, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a Jmeter-Maven project and I'd like to put a modified **jar** file in **"/lib/ext"** folder.

I've added it to “**/src/test/jmeter/lib/ext**”, but seems it doesn't work.

Do I need to add dependencies to my POM file or so?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can add libraries to "lib/ext" folder as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
</configuration>
```

Replace `kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.4` with your own artifact in form of:

```
groupId:artifactId:version
```

References:

- [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)
- [Adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: seems like I have an issue with artifact defining. Here's the jar file that I want to add: testautomationguru.com/download/640, can you help me to define what I need to put inside the <artifact> </artifact>? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Dmitri, any suggestion plz?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JAR files by the following ways:

- You can either add the jar files from jmeter installations into the
  build path of the project
- You can make things easier by adding the maven dependencies in POM.

Add the below dependency in POM.xml file

[image]

For detailed information refer the following link:
https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin

Comment: what do you mean by "add the jar files from jmeter installations into the build path of the project"? to add them to **/src/test/jmeter/** or to **/target/jmeter**?

Comment: Refer the link for adding the JAR files in /lib/ext folder    
                                                                       
https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory

Comment: so, I need to put my jar file to /src/test/jmeter/ and to add to in my POM <jmeterExtensions> <artifact>JAR-NAME</artifact></jmeterExtensions>, right?

Comment: yes. this will work

Comment: seems like I put a wrong name into <artifact> </artifact>. Here's the jar file that I want to add: http://www.testautomationguru.com/download/640/ . Can you tell me please what I need to put on <artifact> </artifact>? Thank you!

Comment: Here's the screenshot of my output: http://take.ms/GZlU1

Comment: Hi, any suggestion plz?